# Kotlin class property that is of type implementing MULTIPLE interfaces

Tags: kotlin, generics

How can I define an property in a class that is of a type that implements MULTIPLE interfaces?

```
    class SupportUsCardViewModel(val id: String?) : RootViewModel() {
    
 -OK----> var favItem: InterfaceMarkAsFavorite? = null
 -OK----> var nameItem: InterfaceWithName? = null
 -fails-> var allItem : (InterfaceMarkAsFavorite, InterfaceWithName)? = null
```

this does not work either:

```
 -fails-> var <T> allItem:T? = null where T: InterfaceMarkAsFavorite
```

what am I missing?

Comment: You can't. You can create another interface that extends from both of above, but this is not entirely the same - value provided for this prop will have to implement not only original interfaces, but the new one as well.

Comment: Woaaw that is a bummer :(

Comment: What you are describing is an "intersection type". See [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/current-intersection-type-options-in-kotlin/20903).

Comment: Very interesting, however not a solution for class properties it seams: "You can’t do this with member properties or with function return types. I haven’t fully understood why yet."